# Outdoor direct vent tankless water heater (low nox) on exterior wall under overhang?

Tags: gas, exhaust-vent, tankless, exhaust

I have an exterior tankless heater that is one of the high-efficiency/low nox type, it has a direct vent (pretty small, actually) just sitting on the top grill.

This is mounted outdoors, but is it safe to mount it on an exterior wall that is a couple feet below an overhang and only about two feet from the very back of the house?  There's still circulation of fresh air around it, I'm tempted to put a sloped ceiling on the overhang to help gas get outside the overhang - it's only about  two feet from the very back of the house.

To be clear, this is not just a short overhang, or a soffit.  This a small room that overhangs the first floor, and the water heater would be under it's floor, just a couple feet away from the back of the house (where it would be difficult to relocate the heater for a variety of reasons)

Here's a sketch - the orange box is the approx heater location:

[image: 3d sketch of the space, the orange box is approx heater location]

Am I worrying about nothing, or am I going to slowly kill my family with gas exhaust?  (or maybe somewhere in between)

Heater is Takagi TK-540X3-NEH (though note that they incorrectly use the photo of the indoor heater on their website which has ducting, the NEH is external and is direct vent).  Manual:

https://www.takagi.com/products/tankless-water-heaters/tk-540x3-neh

Comment: Most of the installation manuals I've seen for these devices give pretty good diagrams specifying how far from soffits, and operable/openable windows and doors. These specifications are usually based on building codes. Some local codes may have further restrictions. Does your product manual not include such a diagram.

Comment: The big concern is CO = Carbon Monoxide. I would make sure there is a CO-detector (they're inexpensive now, very similar to smoke detectors) in the "overhang room".

Comment: @DaveD It does, but it only shows the overhang for a soffit, not for an entire upper room.

Comment: Yes, I think we would definitely put a CO in the overhang, I am just wondering if we're eventually going to need to move it, and/or if it would help to put a slightly slanted covering of the exposed joists in the overhang to help avoid exhaust lingering there, or if it will eventually just blow away as it cools.

Comment: A picture of the area in question would go a long way toward helping to judge the situation. Also, make/model info on the heater are always good. For bonus points, include a link to the installation manual so people don't have to go find it themselves.

Comment: Good point - I'll put up a sketch.  Didn't realize the heater specifics would matter, but I"ll put that up as well.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bother with a sloped ceiling. Outside location means no CO is going to be produced, but if any were it would be swept away. Put a CO detector in the overhanging room.

Comment: Often an inspection is required for a new installation like this. Check with your gas plumbing inspector.